# How do I synchronize Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox, sync, browser-addons, restore

I have a bunch of Firefox extensions. But in case if I have to reinstall my computer, how do I restore them all? Sort of like Dropbox syncing all my files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of ways.

1. Use the [**FEBE**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) and [**CLEO**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2942) addons to create a packaged XPI file that can be installed on one shot
   The **FEBE** addon in itself is quite cool
   but the **CLEO** addon helps package its files together into a single installable 'addon'
2. [Create](http://mashable.com/2009/06/10/firefox-add-on-collections/) your [Firefox Collections](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections) page to download and install whenever required
   The [Addon Collector](https://addons.mozilla.org/pages/collector) would also be useful

Depending on your exact needs, either of the above two schemes will work.

Note that the **FEBE sequence** can actually backup a lot more than just your extension list.
It will also save your preferences and if you choose, your passwords, cookies, bookmarks, etc.
The FEBE method is therefore an excellent way to replicate your firefox installation on another machine
(or even another login on the same machine).

The **Collections method** meanwhile is very good to refer your extension list to someone else, or
get your favorite addons on a different machine where you cannot (or do not want to) access your FEBE backup.

Comment: +1 for FEBE ... simple and does and excellent job.

Comment: Yup. Saves a ton of time.

Answer (score 4):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11778
you might want to try this.

Comment: This `Siphon - Sync` is in Beta at the moment. Would like to know how it compares with FEBE and CLEO.

Comment: It works really well, it's really easy. As easy as xmarks at least

Comment: great extension. +1

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize your extension, you just synchronize your firefox profile.
Use dropbox to synchronize you Firefox profile folder.

Typically I don't synchronize my extensions, this is how I maintain my data consistent
across all computers

On Current System
 1. Bookmark all my extensions on Delicious
 2. I use Foxmarks (now XMarks) to synchronize passwords and bookmarks

Goto second system

1. Install Firefox
2. Install all the bookmarked extensionsr
3. Install XMarks and synchronize your passwords and bookmaks

This way I keep my data consistent across systems, and I still keep
each installation clean (by not copying extensions and profile)

Alternative to Xmarks you may also use Mozilla Weave.

Links:

xmarks.com

mozillalabs.com/weave/